# React Child Calling Parent Method Can't Access State

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have 3 components that are nested `App->GameList->GameItem`

I have a method on the `App(parent)` component that gets call via the `onClick` event in the `GameItem(child)` component

When the `GameItem` component is clicked it fires the `App` component method to access the state in the `App` component.

However when I try to access the state `this.state.gamesVM` I get a

> ***Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'gamesVM' of null***

.

**APP COMPONENT**

```
export default class App extends React.Component {

  state = {
    userId: 3,
    gamesVM: [],
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const pGames = getGames();
    const pPicks = getPicks();
    const pTeams = getTeams();

    Promise.all([pGames, pPicks, pTeams])
      .then(payload => {
        const gamesVM = this.getGamesVM(payload);
        this.setState({gamesVM});
      });
  }

  getGamesVM(payload) {
    // ... code to get and map gamesVM
  }

  teamPicked(team, away, home) { // gets called from child component
    console.log(this.state.gamesVM); // Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'gamesVM' of null
    console.log(this.state.userId); // Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'userId' of null
    // ...
    console.log(this.state.anything); // Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'anything' of null
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <GameList
            gamesVM={this.state.gamesVM}
            teamPicked={this.teamPicked}
          />
          <input type="submit" value="Save" />
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

.

**GAMELIST COMPONENT**

```
export default class GameList extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className='matchups'>
        {this.props.gamesVM.map(game =>
          <GameItem
            teamPicked={this.props.teamPicked}
            key={game.id}
            {...game}
          />
        )}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

.

**GAMEITEM COMPONENT**

```
export default class GameItem extends React.Component {

  render() {

    let awayPickCheckbox = null;

    if (!this.props.isGameStarted) {

      awayPickCheckbox = <li>
            <input type="checkbox" id={this.props.id + this.props.awayTeam} />
            <label
              htmlFor={this.props.id + this.props.awayTeam}
              onClick={this.props.teamPicked.bind(this, 'away', this.props.id + this.props.awayTeam, this.props.id + this.props.homeTeam)}
            >
              {this.props.awayTeam}
            </label>
          </li>;

    } else {

      awayPickCheckbox = <li>
            <label>{this.props.awayTeam}</label>
          </li>
    }


    return (
      <div className="single-matchup">
        <ul className="away-team clearfix">
          {awayPickCheckbox}
        </ul>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

functions inside es6 classes are not bound automatically.

You might define them as properties and anonymous functions like this:

```
teamPicked = (team, away, home) => { // gets called from child component
    console.log(this.state.gamesVM); // Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'gamesVM' of null
    console.log(this.state.userId); // Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'userId' of null
    // ...
    console.log(this.state.anything); // Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'anything' of null
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

You need t0 bind method with `this`.If you forget to bind `this.teamPicked` and pass, `this` will be undefined when the function is actually called.

Inside constructor functin,

```
this.teamPicked = this.teamPicked.bind(this)


 teamPicked(team, away, home) { // gets called from child component
    console.log(this.state.gamesVM); // Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'gamesVM' of null
    console.log(this.state.userId); // Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'userId' of null
    // ...
    console.log(this.state.anything); // Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'anything' of null
  }
```

OR,

```
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <GameList
            gamesVM={this.state.gamesVM}
            teamPicked={this.teamPicked.bind(this)}
          />
          <input type="submit" value="Save" />
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I get a syntax error doing it this way `Syntax error: Unexpected token (278:5)`

Comment: Your edit answer works. Can you clarify what `this` refers to in `App - <GameList teamPicked={this.teamPicked.bind(this)} />` and what it refers to in `GameItem - onClick={this.props.teamPicked.bind(this, 'away', this.props.id + this.props.awayTeam, this.props.id + this.props.homeTeam)}`

Comment: @locnguyen refer this doc: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/handling-events.html. You will have better understanding.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to remove bind function.

```
 <label
                  htmlFor={this.props.id + this.props.awayTeam}
                  onClick={this.props.teamPicked('away', this.props.id + this.props.awayTeam, this.props.id + this.props.homeTeam)}
            >
```